# Is there a way to move around an RDP window that's too big for the screen without using a mouse to move the scrollbar?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop

I keep thinking there might be a shortcut key you can hold down while you move around the screen with the arrow keys.

Comment: Not the direct answer, but something that might help: Try restarting the RDP connection and tell it to run fullscreen - it should match the size of your local monitor, removing the need to scroll. You can also manually set the size of the desktop if you want it smaller.

Comment: I kind of like that manually setting the size of the desktop to smaller...that might be a better way to go...I don't always want it completely full screen because sometimes there are other things to look at on the computer I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - no, sorry.

Slightly less short answer - try resetting the connections screen resolution or fullscreen settings to allow you to avoid having to navigate around with the scroll bars.  You may have to search for and delete default.rdp in your user folder to properly reset this.